# Difference between these frequency response curves

Tags: frequency, damping

I am thinking about a simple mass-damper system response. Most single DOF systems show a frequency response plot that looks like this:
[image: Common frequency response]
Note how increasing the damping ratio always reduces the output response, and at high frequencies, the response approaches the same line regardless of damping ratio.

But, the way I am used to thinking about it, the response should really look like this:
[image: Different? frequency response?]
Note how the increasing the damping ratio reduces the response below $\omega/\omega_0 \cdot  \sqrt{2}$, but increases at frequencies above $\omega/\omega_0 \cdot  \sqrt{2}$.
The response does not approach a downward sloping line as damping ratio increases.  Rather, it approaches $1$ as damping ratio increases.

So what am I missing here?  What is the difference in these two curves?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two frequency response plots are the result of two different models. In the first one, the model is a mass-spring-damper system as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Example:_mass.E2.80.93spring.E2.80.93damper), and the plot shows the ratio of the amplitudes of mass displacement and driving force.

The second plot shows the transmissibility of a single DOF mechanical system as shown below:

[image]

(from *Fundamentals of Mechanical Vibrations* by S.G.Kelly).

Note that here, unlike in the other model, the support is not fixed. The transmissibility shown in your second plot is the ratio of the amplitudes of the mass displacement $x(t)$ and the (forced) displacement of the support $y(t)$.

In formulas, your first plot shows the function

$$M(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2\right)^2+\left(2\zeta\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_0$ is the system's natural frequency, and $\zeta$ is the damping ratio. In electrical engineering terms, this is the magnitude of the frequency response of a second-order low pass filter.

The second plot shows the transmissibility given by Eq. (3.73) in [Kelly's book](http://www.slideshare.net/Alsanea/kelly-sg-fundamentals-of-mechanical-vibrations):

$$T(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\left(2\zeta\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}{{\left(1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2\right)^2+\left(2\zeta\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}}\tag{2}$$

Note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ have the same denominator but different numerators.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I knew I was missing something basic.
Basically, one is a mass-damper model in which a time-varying FORCE is applied to the mass.  The other is a model in which a time-varying DISPLACEMENT is applied to the base.
I found [this that does a good job explaining it too](http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/Notes/vibrations_forced/vibrations_forced.htm)